# How to call Javascript from C# PageLoad?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to ask How to call javascript from C# page load.
My Javascript is

```
function Hide(lst) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var tabList = document.getElementById(lst).style;
            tabList.display = "none";

            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and want to call from pageload

```
if (dtSuperUser(sLogonID).Rows.Count < 1)
        {

            //Call Javascript with parameter name tablist
        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you can use pageOnload event to do so.
Like this.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "<script>document.getElementById('Your element').style.display = 'block'</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "<script>document.getElementById('Your element').style.display = 'hidden'</script>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks... but I used Ajax Toolkit, so need to use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock?

Comment: when I use the code which you provided, that is not hide, it show code on UI page when I call the page. thanks

Comment: When page first open the IsPostBack==false; So you should use 'Hidden' in the else. I just show an example. Sorry for that.

Comment: this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "urScriptName", "alert(1);");

Answer (score 1):

```
String csName = "myScript";
Type csType = this.GetType();

// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

// Check to see if the client script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
{
  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, 
      string.Format("Hide({0})", lst.ClientID));
}
```

Comment: I got this message, "Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Type'" to '_______.Type'

Answer (score 1):

```
RegisterStartupScript("Hide", string.Format(@"if (document.getElementById) {
        var tabList = document.getElementById('{0}').style;
        tabList.display = 'none';
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }",lst));
```

Or if you already have the Javascript function rendered in the Markup

```
RegisterStartupScript("Hide",string.Format("Hide('{0}');",lst));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using webforms or MVC?  If using webforms check:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa479011

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("MyScript",
   "<script language=javascript>" +
   "function AlertHello() { alert('Hello ASP.NET'); }</script>");

Button1.Attributes["onclick"] = "AlertHello()";
Button2.Attributes["onclick"] = "AlertHello()";
```

Comment: I dun want to use button, bro. I check permission and want to disable html tab